# How to execute part of code one per day in Adapter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I would like to execute part of code one per day. I am using SharedPreferences to achieve this, and basically code works fine but it works only for the first item in DataAdadpter. I must use this piece of code  for all adapter's items.

```
  Calendar calendar24h = Calendar.getInstance();
        int currentDay = calendar24h.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        SharedPreferences settingsSharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0);
        int lastDay = settingsSharedPreferences.getInt("day", 0);


        if (lastDay != currentDay) {


            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settingsSharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putInt("day", currentDay);
            editor.apply();


            holder.addProfit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.addProfit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    holder.addProfit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Toasty.success(mCtx,"Salary added to "+holder.goalName.getText().toString(),Toasty.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        }
```

Comment: Hey WireWer, it's not exactly clear how the code is structured and what you are trying to achieve. Generally you can pass the result of `lastDay != currentDay` as Boolean to the adapter and use it as a variable in all items with the `onBindView()` function. Would this work for you?

Comment: @Viktor Stojanov thank you for your answer. Could you show me any example of this?

Comment: Just calculate and save `lastDay != currentDay` as a variable inside the Adapter and use it use inside the bind method.